# Edit frame in a page with synonyms fields

Tags: experience-editor, mvc, razor

I'm new to experience editor in sitecore.
I'm writing an edit frame in razor page using as datasource the page item ID. The edit frame should modify some fields read by a rendering in the page.
But when i'm specifing the fields that should be edited by the edit frame, separating them with the pipe '|' character, how to distinguish more fields that have the same name?

Comment: You shouldn't _have_ fields with the same name.

Comment: You can't do that you need to make field name unique